# Simple query is really slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have this query that it takes 36s to execute and I don't understand why or how could I improve it. Any help?

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p INNER JOIN product_store ps ON p.id = ps.product_id
INNER JOIN stores s ON s.id = ps.store_id WHERE s.city = 'Berlin' GROUP BY p.id LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

Those are the following numbers:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM products;
```

43309

```
SELECT count(*) FROM product_store;
```

1456445

```
SELECT count(*) FROM stores;
```

155

I imagine that it could be for the relationship table but 36s is too much for 16 rows.

Any idea how to improve this query?

EDIT:

For any reason, the problem is not by Postgres but by Hibernate. The query is quite fast in pgAdmin 4 but really slow in Hibernate.

Thanks, everybody!

EDIT 2:

Analysis

[image: analysis]

EDIT 3:

Sorry, this is the real problem when I add "DISTINCT"

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM products p INNER JOIN product_store ps ON p.id = ps.product_id
INNER JOIN stores s ON s.id = ps.store_id WHERE s.city = 'Berlin' GROUP BY p.id LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

PRODUCTION
[image: analyze]

LOCAL
[image: analyze]

Comment: Are you making use of any indexing? Have you looked at the EXPLAIN plan for the query?

Comment: Try to post [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) output for the query

Comment: "*36s is too much for 16 rows*" - not directly related to your problem, but: the runtime of a query is not (necessarily) determined by the number of rows it returns. If you search a needle in a haystack it probably takes ages but you only "return" a single needle (=row) from that

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: `select p.* ... group by p.id` is *at least* bad style. Without any aggregate functions, `GROUP BY` makes no sense.

Comment: Added analyze, it seems a problem with Hibernate

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as plain text (the way I mentioned in my previous comment) rather than hard-to-read screen shots.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added, the problem was with the DISTINCT, that makes the query slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregation is a big issue.  I would suggest using `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM product_store ps INNER JOIN
                   stores s 
                   ON s.id = ps.store_id
              WHERE p.id = ps.product_id AND s.city = 'Berlin' 
             )
LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

Then be sure you have indexes on `product_store(product_id, store_id)`.  I assume you already have an index on `stores(id)` -- because that should be the primary key.

Comment: Would it not makes the query slower because the subquery?

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez: why do you think a sub-query makes it slower?

Comment: As far as I know, the subqueries are slower than the joins

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez They are not. In most cases they generate similar plans. The `EXISTS(...)` is actually more efficient, because the *subquery*-scan can skip to the *next*  after hitting the first found/matching record.

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez: that might be true for MySQL but not for any DBMS with a modern query optimizer

Comment: Still is a problem with DISTINCT, it duplicates the rows

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez . . . This query can only duplicate rows if you have duplicates in the `products` table.  That seems unlikely, but if you do have duplicates, you should fix the *data* rather than trying to work around the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad you are right, it was with the IN query

Comment: After some tests, this is the best answer! From 36s now it is less than 1 second! Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `IN` instead because the selective predicate is in the subquery. It's better to use `EXISTS` if the selective predicate is in parent query. When you use `IN`, the optimizer writes the subquery to a view and then joins to `products` table through a unique index. Please check execution plans of using both `EXISTS` and `IN` to see the difference.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p 
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT ps.product_id
              FROM product_store ps 
              JOIN stores s ON s.id = ps.store_id
              WHERE p.id = ps.product_id AND s.city = 'Berlin' 
             )
LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Still is a problem with DISTINCT, it duplicates the rows